# Does QTP knowledge required on learning Quality Center

Tags: hp-quality-center

I'm newbie to Quality Center, Hence please clarify that one has to have some knowledge on QTP while learning Quality Center tool. Since found a module exist as QTP-QC integration.

Anxiously Awaiting,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know QTP to learn QC.  They are both different tools.  QTP-QC integration is required when using QTP as an automation tool to execute/manage QTP scripts and resource in Quality Center.

Answer (score 0):

I agree--you don't need QTP, but if you want to use it you can integrate it by following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qc/qtp_qc_integration.htm). However, I work for IT Central Station, a crowdsourced review site for enterprise tech products including QC, and our users say that if you’re new to QC or ALM, they have a "steep learning curve" so it would be helpful to take a course in it. [This user](http://www.itcentralstation.com/product_reviews/hp-alm-review-25119-by-alex-kriegel?tid=thread-pr04-cm02-t002-l01) recommends that you check out HP’s “tutorials (PDF, movie files, online resources) on how to use the application, as well as a number of classes to familiarize yourself with the product...to learn about many best practices, ways to organize your projects for maximum reuse through libraries and templates, configuring KPI and dashboards.” Hope this helps.